# Highcharts: Format all numbers with comma?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and I want to format all numbers showed anywhere in the chart (tooltips, axis labels...) with comma-separated thousands.

Otherwise, the default tooltips and labels are great, and i want to keep them exactly the same.

For example, in this chart, the number should be `2,581,326.31` but otherwise exactly the same.

[image]

How can I do this?

I tried adding:

```
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: "{point.y:,.0f}"
    }
```

But this got rid of the nice circle and series label in the tooltip - I'd like to keep that. And ideally I'd prefer to use a single option to set global number formatting, across the whole chart.

Comment: I would try with a custom lang, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419358/highcharts-datetime-localization

Answer (score 140, accepted):

This can be set with the `thousandSep` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.thousandsSep)) global option.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        thousandsSep: ','
    }
});
```

See [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wjerxvoa/).

Comment: Some might find the `decimalPoint` option related and useful. [See API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.decimalPoint).

Comment: The default thousands separator looks to be a space now. Has something changed in their API? Even their example is showing it as a space instead of a comma in the tooltip. http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/rmTWS/

Comment: Space is default from Highcharts 4.1.0. Before that it was comma. "Use space as the default thousands separator. It is culture independent and ISO standard." https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/6cc2a45c7c4ca0cc9bd61f9ad665b71fea9f4a15

Comment: Thanks! Now how do you set the y-axis with commas too?

Comment: Odd.. this works in your jsFiddle but it doesn't work in my code... I still get spaces.

Comment: Found the solution to my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265675/how-to-set-lang-property-in-highcharts-using-angular-js

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to show numbers without commas and spaces.

eg. by default 9800 shows as 9 800.

If you want 9800 to be shown as 9800

you can try this in tooltip:

```
    tooltip: {
     pointFormat: '<span>{point.y:.f}</span>'
   }
```

Comment: That needs to be adjusted for shared tooltips.

Answer (score 5):

This way worked with me.

I configured in yAxis option.

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this through all the answers cause I was interested in display on the yAxis

Comment: After around 4 hours of searching on the internet, I got this answer that worked for me.

Thanks @Hien

Answer (score 0):

This way work for me.

I use Angular 10 and I did this for Tooltip and yAxis.

for yAxis use `numberFormat`:

```
 labels: {
              format: '{value}',
              style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
              },
              formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 3);
            }
            },
```

and for Tooltip :

```
{point.y:.f}
```