# How to give proper number denominations in highcharts buuble chart

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I am using bubble chart from highcharts. If i hover over a bubble it shows the tooltip information.In that, the "sugar intake" value is appearing with a space in between to represent denominations as 9 500.

```
Is there a way to change that to 9,500 ?
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t48xyg9o/1/
Please refer this image
[bubblechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6oFv.png)

Comment: Sort of like using [thousand separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29209562/2732991)?

Comment: Thanks @Halvor, i went through the thread and find this "{point.y:.f}". this removes the gap 9 500 to 9500. Do you know a way to attach a comma in the place of the space like 9,500

Comment: You can change the default [thousand seperator](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang.thousandsSep)

Comment: The thing is i am using highcharts-vue and passing just the JSON to display the chart. there i cant able to run a separate function as shown in the link. is there a way to set the setOptions parameters inside the JSON which is shown in my jsfiddle link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue/#using-highcharts-setoptions-method), you can change the thousand separator like this

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    thousandsSep: ','
  }
});
```