# how to set character limit to 4-5 in axis labels in highcharts in angular 7

Tags: highcharts, angular7, axis-labels

I'm using column, I need to reduce x axis characters to max 4-5 character which is dynamically coming from database.

xAxis: {
categories: labesldata,
        crosshair: true
      }

Comment: This should be done at data manipulation level, not a highchart issue IMHO.

Comment: yeah. but can we do it at highcharts?. using formatter: function (). I tried.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60614830/2288436

Comment: formatter: function () {
            return  this.value.toString().substring(0, 5);
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `formatter` callback function and modify the default string:

```
xAxis: {
  ...,
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return this.value.slice(0, 5);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4931/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: i've used 
 
formatter: function () {
return  this.value.toString().substring(0, 5);
 }

this works fine. But I want to display the whole level in tooltip too.

Comment: Hi @Deep Shikha, What do you exactly mean? What is 'whole level' for you?

Comment: sorry that was typo. I meant to say x-axis labels.

Comment: @Deep Shikha, In the example that I have provided, the entire category name is displayed