# Retain decimal seperator on export excel in Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

This is my values that I am getting in datatable.

```
Cuenta  Nombre Cuenta       Oct18   Dec18   Sep19   Oct19   M$      M%  A$      A%
11      Activos Liquidos    5732,12 6950,89 5879,21 5965,02 85,82   1.4 232,91  4.06
```

When exporting the excel the data's decimal place gets converted to 5732.12  6950.89 ..etc. I need to preserve the decimal I am using datatables.

I used this code:

```
{
      extend: 'excel',
      exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible',
          format: {
              body: function(data, row, column, node) {
                  data = $('<p>' + data + '</p>').text();
                  return $.isNumeric(data.replace(',', '.')) ? data.replace(',', '.') : data;
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

But it changes my 4.06 to 4,06 which is incorrect. How to achieve this? Thank you.

Update :

This is the value I am getting in excel

[image: This is what I am getting but completely wrong]

Comment: isNumeric fails on the numbers with decimal comma. Then Excel will show whatever is in its locale setting. On my Excel it is decimal comma. What is the complete expected output?

Comment: I have set the locale as Spanish but in excel it is getting converted to '.'

Comment: Why is 4.06 wrong? I would have thought `573.212` was the wrong value

Comment: Also what is the point of `$('<p>' + data + '</p>').text();`

Comment: I would consider this instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159354/how-do-i-find-the-decimal-separator-for-current-locale-in-javascript

Comment: @mplungjan to avoid strip errors and then strip all the HTML tags

Comment: So why is 4.06 not 4.06 in Spanish?

Comment: It is 4.06 in spanish as well.

Comment: But YOU said that 4,06 is incorrect. 4,06 IS in my opinion correct and 573.212 is your problem

Comment: Sorry it is same as the client is saying it is the correct value.

Comment: I just retain the same values in datatable in excel as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```js
const fields = "11\tActivos Liquidos\t5732,12\t6950,89\t5879,21\t5965,02\t85,82\t1.4\t232,91\t4.06".trim().split("\t")
  .map(fld => /^\d/.test(fld) ? parseFloat(fld.replace(/,/,".")) : fld);
console.log(JSON.stringify(fields))
```

Comment: Where should I paste this ?

Comment: You need to add `.map(fld => /^\d/.test(fld) ? parseFloat(fld.replace(/,/,".")) : fld);` to the array that holds the values. How you get the array is dependent on the strings. I guessed tab delimited